# How can I check the size of a SQL table row in b/kb/mb?

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures

I'm aware of a `sp_spaceused` stored procedure to check the size of a SQL table or it's database, but is there a way to check the size of a single table row?

**What I've Tried:**

- Running `sp_spaceused` on the table before and after inserting a row (it doesn't change the result of the `sp_spaceused` query as the row is not substantial enough in size)

Comment: I know the answer comes late but I had some similar problem and I thought that though it's not a very precise solution maybe you could approximate by making a sql dump of the table with data. 
The sql dump format would differ from the format of stored db data but from that I think you can think of an upper limit value in hdd space for data.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion. Or I could take the whole table size, then split it into rows. To be honest, I can't even remember why I was trying to do this, or what job I was in when needing to haha. Been a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often use a script I found [here](http://power-programming.co.uk/post/2010/02/26/TSQL-Identify-space-used-by-tables-in-a-way-that-can-be-analysed.aspx) to get the size and even more infos. I am shure you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. A very nice script. It doesn't show me each row size in bytes but I'll look into adapting it.